# Unexpected Ruby output compared to shell?

Tags: ruby

I was in the middle of writing some Nagios plugins and came across strange issues. I don't know if I am missing something but the command being executed in Ruby does not return the same results as shell:

```
[root@myhost~]# pgrep -f ntpd | wc -l
1
[root@myhost~]# irb
irb(main):001:0> `pgrep -f ntpd | wc -l`
=> "2\n"
[root@myhost~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

This outputs as expected:

```
irb(main):009:0> `pgrep -f ntpd`.chomp
=> "23198"
```

According to [the backticks documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-60), the method should return STDOUT of the command as a string.

Any ideas? I feel there is some basic principle I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Not able to duplicate.  I get 1 from both the command line and irb.  Try each several times.  Do you get the same result consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states, backticks `returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell.` so the extra number that you see (`2` instead of `1`) is the result of Ruby executing this command.

Since `pgrep -f pattern` will match the full command, it also counts the result of irb executing `pgrep`. If you try without `-f` you will see `1`.

To have a better look at what is happenning behind the scene, you can mess in irb with

```
pgrep -f -l ntpd | wc -l && sleep 20
```

You should see something like an extra `sh` which corresponds to irb executing the following process:

```
sh -c pgrep -l -f ntpd && sleep 20
```

Comment: doh. I can't believe I missed something as stupid as the -f flag. Silly me, thank you for the clarification!